# How to Flag Revised Person Records Across Multiple Entries

Tags: excel

I have around 7000 personnel records that I need to sort and flag for revisions. This is HR records that contain person name, qualifications, validity period of the qualification, and the date it was achieved (start date)

The is set out as so:

```
|FirstName|LastName|StartDate|EndDate|Version|QualificationID|QualificationName|
```

What I am trying to do is flag the records for renewals using a version column. The logic is that if the same qualification appears more than once, I need to identify which is the most current version easily with a revision number and add that in with a formula or macro:

```
|FirsName|LastName|StartDate|EndDate|Version|QualificationID|QualificationName|
|FRANK    |ARCHER  |11/08/2014|24/05/2015| 1|30005849|APPOINTED ASSESSOR
|FRANK    |ARCHER  |25/05/2015|24/05/2114| 2|30005849|APPOINTED ASSESSOR
```

I have tried some custom sorting then referencing formulas but cant figure out how to do it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what version of excel are you using? Finding the most current version is not the same as identifying which one needs to be renewed. Please confirm what the expected output should look like based on your sample data?

Comment: Office 365 Terry.  I just want to flag it as renewed in the end. But also want the versioning number. If the version is greater than 1 for each entry, i can assume it is renewed.

Comment: so you want to remove all older versions for each qualification, and if the version number is `1`, you want to `highlight` it in some way so you know that you need to renew it. Will there be case that the version number is greater than `1` and you still need to renew the qualification, so would it be safer to check the qualification by the `EndDate` instead of version number, or version number is safe enough?

Comment: It is going into a HR database so all of them need to go in. The front end logic is that it will hide all "Renewed" skills. In the database its 1 or 0 if it is renewed or not. I have stared at it too long that the process is probably really simple! - The end date is probably a better idea as you say. As a qualification may expire on X date but the person may choose to renew it sooner and add the start date before it expires.

Comment: 1. If person and qual are the same, 
2. check expiry date, 
3. version incrementally based on oldest to newest 1,2,3 etc

Comment: So you want to add a new column to show a new version number for each qual, and also add a second column to show either `1` or `0` indicating if it is current or out of date?